# Can I change the fill color within geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I plot geom_density, I can change the fill at key values

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)

P <- .65
K <- 1e3
SIMS <- 4e3

df <- 
    tibble(
        recipe_a = rbinom(SIMS, K, P) / K,
        recipe_b = rbinom(SIMS, K, P) / K,
        treat_a = recipe_a-recipe_b,
        treat_b = recipe_b-recipe_a
    )

CRIT <- quantile(df$treat_b, c(.025, .975))

df |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = treat_b, fill = treat_b > CRIT[[2]] | treat_b < CRIT[[1]])) +
    geom_histogram(bins=50)
```

[image]

Can this also be done with geom_density()?

```
df |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = treat_b, fill = treat_b > CRIT[[2]] | treat_b < CRIT[[1]])) +
    geom_density(bins=50, position='identity') +
    labs(fill = "Stat Sig")
```

[image]

The geom_density() output is creating multiple density plots. I have tried setting group=1, but this prevents the fill argument from working at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
dens <- density(
            df$treat_b, 
            n = 2^12 # number of points at which to estimate density
            )
df2 <- 
    tibble(
        x = dens$x,
        y = dens$y
    )

df2 |> 
    mutate(myfill = x > CRIT[[2]] | x < CRIT[[1]]) |> 
    ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
    geom_line() + 
    geom_segment(
        aes(xend = x, yend = 0, color = myfill)
        ) + 
    labs(fill = "Stat Sig")
```

[image]